# Error in transposing matrix using Eigen C++ library

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am trying to take transpose of a matrix of dimension 1024X3 using Eigen library's built in function .transpose(),but I got erroneous result i.e. some values which were zeros appear as -6.27744e+066 , while the nonzero values are all right. My matrix has only three rows nonzero ,other all rows are zero. I tried doing the transpose without using .transpose as follow

```
MatrixXd RGB_transpose(3,1024)    ///My Matrix
for(int i=0;i<1024)
{
RGB_transpose.col(i)=RGB.row(i);    /////RGB is the original matrix
}
```

but got the same result only. If anyone has the idea to solve this problem please give me.

Comment: What do you do to that matrix before? Zeros appear as e+66!? This sounds more like you corrupted the matrix than transpose failing you....

Comment: I didn't do anything with the matrix,once I have the RGB matrix I am trying to compute its transpose.

Comment: How did you get the RGB matrix (as in how are the non-zero values filled in)?

Comment: My RGB matrix is fine,I have checked its content. In Matlab I am getting the correct result but here only getting error.

Comment: How did you check the contents? If using a debug mode the zeroes might be zero initialized and therefore not the same as when in a release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Stick to `RGB_transpose=RGB.transpose();`  and if there is a problem with the values, try to solve THAT problem, not create a whole new problem ("how to transpose without using .transpose()").
Post an actual piece of code (the smallest possible that reproduces the problem) and the error messages or warnings that you got, and your problem will be solved extremely fast.